# combocox text value is set to null even though datagridview selected cell value returns a string

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I am developing a windows form application using async and await functions. I have multiple dependent combobox controls where  c2 is depends on c1 value and datagridview is loaded based on inputs. when user clicks on datagridview cell, c1 text is set according to selected cell value but c2 text is set to null even though selected cell value return string. please find below code snippet

```
private void dgvAsset_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataGridViewCell cell = null; // set cell initial value to null
        foreach (DataGridViewCell selectedcell in dgvAsset.SelectedCells)
             {
                 cell = selectedcell; // load selected cell value
                 break;
             }
        if (cell != null)
        {
            DataGridViewRow sr = cell.OwningRow;
            assetID = Convert.ToInt32(sr.Cells["AssetID"].Value.ToString());
            txtAssId.Text = sr.Cells["Asset_ID"].Value.ToString();
            cbAssType.Text = sr.Cells["Asset_Type"].Value.ToString();
            txtAsSerNo.Text = sr.Cells["AssetSerialNo"].Value.ToString();
            txtAssDesc.Text = sr.Cells["Asset_Description"].Value.ToString();
            dtAFrom.Text = sr.Cells["AllocatedFrom"].Value.ToString();
            dtATo.Text = sr.Cells["AllocatedTo"].Value.ToString();
            cbProjCode.Text = sr.Cells["Project_Code"].Value.ToString();
           // this.cbProjCode.SelectionChangeCommitted -= new EventHandler(cbProjCode_SelectionChangeCommitted);
           // string port = sr.Cells["Portfolio"].Value.ToString();
           /* the below 3 combobox are set to null*/
            cbPortfolio.Text = Convert.ToString(sr.Cells["Portfolio"].FormattedValue.ToString())
            cbPOwner.Text = sr.Cells["Primary_Owner"].Value.ToString();
            cbSOwner.Text = sr.Cells["Seconday_Owner"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }

public async Task LoadProjectCode() 
{ 
    List<string> projectCode = new List<string>(); 
    projectCode = await func.LoadProjectCode(); 
// this.cbProjCode.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(cbProjCode_SelectedIndexChanged); 
    cbProjCode.DataSource = projectCode; 
    cbProjCode.SelectedIndex = -1; 
} 




private async void cbProjCode_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    cbProjCode.Enabled = false; 
    cbAssType.Enabled = true; 
    cbPortfolio.Enabled = true; 
    cbPOwner.Enabled = true; 
    cbSOwner.Enabled = true; 
    txtAssDesc.Enabled = true; 
    txtAsSerNo.Enabled = true; 
    txtAssId.Enabled = true; ProjectCodeId = await func.GetProjectCodeID(cbProjCode.Text); 
    await LoadPortfolio(); 
}
```

Same code worked fine when I was not using async and await to load comboboxes and combobox selectedindexchange event was used instead of selectioncommitted earlier.

Comment: You are suggesting that the async stuff is the problem, but you're not showing that code.

Comment: I am not sure if its async or selection committed. Please find below the code..

Comment: I did some testings and found that the issue is caused because of selectionchangecommitted event. If i place the code to load cbportfolio in cbprojectcode selection indexchanged event it is working fine.

Comment: issue is i am disabling selectionindexchange event before binding datasource to cbportfolio and i am not sure when to enable it. enabling after databound is throwing connection string open error..